# Usage of the const keyword

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, constants, c99

I know that using the `const` keyword on function arguments provides better performance, but I always forget to add it. Is the compiler (GCC in this case) smart enough to notice that the variabele never changes during the function, and compile it as if I would have added `const` explicitly?

Comment: It may, if you turn on certain optimization flags. Consult the GCC manual.

Comment: I'm not sure there are many places that a compiler can really take advantage of `const` when optimizing...

Comment: *"I know that using the `const` keyword on function arguments provides better performance"* - Well, I certainly don't know that (but this may be just me being misinformed).

Comment: @ChristianRau: "provides better performance" is a bold claim and you're right to doubt it, but it enables certain optimizations in certain cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the compiler (GCC in this case) smart enough to notice that the
>   variabele never changes during the function, and compile it as if I
>   would have added const explicitly?

Not necessarily. For example:

```
void some_function(int *ptr); // defined in another translation unit

int foo(int a) {
    some_function(&a);
    return a + 1;
}
```

The compiler can't see what `some_function` does, so it can't assume that it won't modify `a`.

Link-time optimization could perhaps see what `some_function` really does and act accordingly, but as far as this answer is concerned I'll consider only optimization for which the definition of `some_function` is unavailable.

```
int bar(const int a) {
    some_function((int*)&a);
    return a + 1;
}
```

The compiler can't see what `some_function` does, but it *can* assume that the value of `a` does not change anyway. Therefore it can make any optimizations that apply: maybe it can keep `a` in a callee-saves register across the call to `some_function`; maybe it computes the return value before making the call instead of after, and zaps `a`. The program has undefined behavior if `some_function` modifies `a`, and so from the compiler's POV once that happens it doesn't matter whether it uses the "right" or "wrong" value for `a`.

So, by in this example by marking `a` const you have told the compiler something that it cannot otherwise know -- that `some_function` will not modify `*ptr`. Or anyway that if it does modify it, then you don't care what your program's behavior is.

```
int baz(int a) {
    some_function(NULL);
    return a + 1;
}
```

Here the compiler can see all relevant code *as far as the standard is concerned*. It doesn't know what `some_function` does, but it does know that it doesn't have any standard means to access `a`. So it should make no difference whether `a` is marked const or not because the compiler knows it doesn't change anyway.

Debugger support can complicate this situation, of course -- I don't know how things stand with `gcc` and `gdb`, but in theory at least if the compiler wants to support you breaking in with the debugger and modifying `a` manually then it might not treat it as unmodifiable. The same applies to the possibility that `some_function` uses platform-specific functionality to walk up the stack and mess with `a`. Platforms don't *have* to provide such functionality, but if they do then it conflicts with optimization.

I've seen an old version of gcc (3.x, can't remember x) that failed to make certain optimizations where I failed to make a local `int` variable `const`, but in my case gcc 4 did make the optimization. Anyway, the case I'm thinking of wasn't a parameter, it was an automatic variable initialized with a constant value.

There's nothing special about `a` being a parameter in any of what I've said -- it could just as well be any automatic variable defined in the function. Mind you, the only way to for a parameter to get the effect of initialization with a constant value is to call the function with a constant value, and for the compiler to observe the value *for that call*. This tends to happen only when the function is inlined. So inlined calls to functions can have additional optimizations applied to them that the "out-of-line" function body isn't eligible for.

Comment: Wow, very thorough treatment of the issues.

Answer (score 4):

You have a common misunderstanding about `const`. Only making an *object* `const` means that its value never changes, and then it's not just during a function, it *never* changes.

Making a parameter to a function `const` does *not* mean its value never changes, it just means that function cannot change the value [through that `const` pointer](http://ideone.com/3NzrYK). The value can change other ways.

For example, look at this function:

```
void f(const int* x, int* y)
{
    cout << "x = " << *x << endl;
    *y = 5;
    cout << "x = " << *x << endl;
}
```

Notice that it takes a `const` pointer to `x`. However, what if you call it like this:

```
int x = 10;
f(&x, &x);
```

Now, `f` has a `const` pointer, but it's to a non-const object. So the *value* can change, and it does since `y` is a non-`const` pointer to the *same* object. All of this is perfectly legal code. There's no funny business here.

So there's really no answer to your question since it's based entirely on false premises.

Comment: I was thinking about parameters passed by value. When the function cannot change them, there seem no other possibilities for them to be changed. You are right that when passing pointers things may be different.

Comment: @Joshua: In that case, the object really is `const` and that's a promise that its value will never, ever change. Generally speaking, there's no way the compiler could figure that out because even if you only call `const` functions, non a non-`const` object, the compiler can't assume the values won't change, and the compiler generally can't look into every function you call. (If it can, then it could figure that out by itself. But it can't just assume all `const` functions don't modify values. They are allowed to if the object is non-const.)

Comment: Your answer & comments are as if it was about C++, but isn't this question about C only?

Comment: Ack! You all are right! Sorry, I cannot delete this answer because it has been accepted.

Comment: You could make this answer apply to C by changing the reference to a pointer. Then you'd be talking about parameters passed by pointer-to-const, which is *one* way of "using the `const` keyword on function arguments" but not the only way.

Answer (score 2):

*const*, much like *inline*, is only a hint for a compiler and does not guarantee any performance gains. The more important task of *const* is to protect programmers from themselves so they do not unwilling modify variables where they shouldn’t be modified.

Answer (score 1):

1) Really const is **not** affecting your performance directly. It may in some cases make simpler points-to analysis (so prefer `const char*` to `char*`), but const is more about semantics and readability of your code.

2) CV-qualified type forms different type in C and C++. So your compiler, even if it sees profit from making default const, will not do it, because it will change type and may lead to surprisingly odd things.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the optimization the compiler is taking a deep look at when memory locations are read or written. So the compiler is quite good at detecting when a variable is not changed (const) and when it is changed. The optimizer does not need you to tell him when a variable is const.

Nevertheless you should always use const when appropriate. Why? Because it makes interfaces more clear and easier to understand. And it helps detect bugs when you are changing a variable that you did not want to change.